# Divide return from array?

Tags: php

I got an array that outputs data into an xml. It looks like this:

```
        $data = array(
            'trip_id'      => $this->trip_id,
            'from'         => $this->from,
            'from_lat'     => $this->from_lat,
            'from_lon'     => $this->from_lon,
            'to'           => $this->to,
            'to_lat'       => $this->to_lat,
            'to_lon'       => $this->to_lon,
            'when'         => $this->when,
            'when_iso'     => date('Y-m-d H:i', $this->when),
            'details'      => $this->details,
            'got_car'      => $this->got_car,
            'inserted'     => $this->inserted,
            'name'         => $this->name,
            'email'        => $this->email,
            'phone'        => $this->phone,
        );
```

$this_when contains a unix timestamp and I would like to add a new type of time wich is when_rel, it should contain the number of days from today that the unix timestamp refers to. (1, 2 etc.)

I would like t know how to apply math to a value fetched from an array. I tried this but it just puts out an error:

```
            'when_rel'     => ($this->when/60);
```

Comment: please update your question with more appropriate code snippet, all the above does not make sense (obviously is syntax error)

Comment: completely rewritten, hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, finally everything make sense, also, what are the error return?

Comment: Should work fine. What is `$this->when`? Please post the results of a `var_dump($this->when)`. And if you're getting errors, please post those too.

Comment: Does the code you tested really have a semicolon inside the array definition? It should be a comma, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `'when_rel' => ($this->when/60)`?

Answer (score 2):

just like what you did with when_iso:

```
'when_rel'     => date('d', $this->when),
```

Also what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you are messing up the array's closing parenthesis? I just made this example, and division like that *should* work just fine, in normal circumstances:

```
<?php 

class Foo {
    public $num;

    public function  __construct() {
        $this->num = 234534253454;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$arr = array('hello' => ($foo->num / 60), 'blah' => 'foo');
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [hello] => 3908904224.23
    [blah] => foo
)
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/WcAq1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch for your test, as grossvogel pointed out, there was a semi-colon rather than a "," occram turned out to be right, once again!